# Renaming Multiples Files with Different Names in a Directory using shell

Tags: shell, rename, file-rename

I've found most of the questions of this kind where the change in name has been same for the entire set of files in that directory.
But i'm here presented with a situation to give a different name to every file in that directory or just add a different prefix.

For Example, I have about 200 files in a directory, all of them with numbers in their filename. what i want to do is add a prefix of 1 to 200 for every file. Like 1_xxxxxxxx.png,2_xxxxxxxx.png...........200_xxxxxxxx.png

I'm trying this, but it doesnt increment my $i everytime, rather it gives a prefix of 1_ to every file.

```
echo "renaming files" 
i=1                                             #initializing
j=ls -1 | wc -l                                 #Count number of files in that dir
while [ "$i" -lt "$j" ]                         #looping 
do
    for FILE in * ; do NEWFILE=`echo $i_$FILE`; #swapping the file with variable $i
    mv $FILE $NEWFILE                           #doing the actual rename
    i=`expr $i+1`                               #increment $i
done
```

Thanks for any suggestion/help.

Answer (score 1):

To increment with `expr`, you definitely need spaces( `expr $i + 1` ), but you would probably be better off just doing:

```
echo "renaming files" 
i=1
for FILE in * ; do
    mv $FILE $((i++))_$FILE
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i=1
for f in *; do
  mv -- "$f" "${i}_$f"
  i=$(($i + 1))
done
```